# Inner approximation and outer approximation of winning set

Tags: descriptive-set-theory

Consider a [Gale-Stewart game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_determinacy_theorem#Gale.E2.80.93Stewart_games) with a Borel winning set $W$ and a finite action space $A$ at each stage, which we denote as $G(W)$.

For a winning set $C$, $V(G(C))$, the value of $G(C)$, is $1$, if Player $1$ wins, that is the outcome is in $C$.  $V(G(C))=0$, if Player $2$ wins.

Does there necessarily exist two winning sets, an open set $U$ and a closed set $F$,and $F \subseteq W \subseteq U$, such that $V(G(F))=V(G(U))$?

**Added**: I initially asked whether it's necessarily the case there exists an open set $U$ and a closed set $F$,and $U \subseteq W \subseteq F$, $V(G(F))=V(G(U))$ with the order of $F \subseteq W \subseteq U$ reversed. It's not true since there exists a winning set with an empty interior that player $1$ has a winning strategy.